# Modify JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON object :

```
var myObject = {"priorityset": 
  [
    {"name":"Prio1", "valueA":"0", "valueB":"0", "valueC":"0", "valueD":"1"}, 
    {"name":"Prio2", "valueA":"1", "valueB":"0", "valueC":"0", "valueD":"1"}, 
    {"name":"Prio3", "valueA":"0", "valueB":"0", "valueC":"0", "valueD":"1"}
  ]
};
```

I want to modify this object so I get something like this:

```
var myObject = 
[
  {"name":"Prio1", "valueA":"0", "valueB":"0", "valueC":"0", "valueD":"1"}, 
  {"name":"Prio2", "valueA":"1", "valueB":"0", "valueC":"0", "valueD":"1"}, 
  {"name":"Prio3", "valueA":"0", "valueB":"0", "valueC":"0", "valueD":"1"}
];
```

I have tried to solve this by myself, but no solution so far. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "There's no such thing as a ['JSON Object'](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, json is a string-based data format.  You have an object literal with a property, the value of which is an array that contains object literals.  From what I see, you just want the property.

`myObject = myObject.priorityset;`

Equally valid is

`myObject = myObject['priorityset'];`

which is another way to do property access on an object literal.